# Tkinter frame problem : resizing does not work

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to be able to use nested frames but there is a weird behavior : when I enter the height and width parameters they seem to not work. I use .grid() Is that what is causing the problem ? I use ttk Frame, is there some behavior I do not know about ?

I looked at the documentation but nothing seemed to be helping. I tried changing the parameters but I didn't help either.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("Tk test")
root.geometry("800x800")

frame_1 = ttk.Frame(root, height=400, width=400, relief="sunken")\
frame_1.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=1)
frame_2 = ttk.Frame(frame_1, height=200, width=200, relief="sunken")\
frame_2.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=1, sticky="N, S, W, E")
label_1 = ttk.Label(frame_2, text="Text")
label_1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="S, W, N, E")

root.mainloop()
```

Expected result : there is a sunken frame inside another sunken frame. Inside the nested frame there is a label named "Text"
Actual result : The label is always in the upper left corner and does not want to move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give cells on a grid a minimum size using the `grid_columnconfigure()` and `grid_rowconfigure` methods, as [documented here](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm).

Applied to your code (along with other corrections & improvements):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tk test")
root.geometry("800x800")

frame_1 = ttk.Frame(root, height=400, width=400, relief="sunken")
frame_1.grid(row=0, column=0)

frame_2 = ttk.Frame(frame_1, height=200, width=200, relief="sunken")
frame_2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NSWE")
frame_2.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=200)
frame_2.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=200)

label_1 = ttk.Label(frame_2, text="Text")
label_1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NW")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Don't I need to use rowspan and columnspan with the frames ?

Comment: Jonathcraft: I don't think so—at least not yet. The span options are used to make a single cell occupy the space normally reserved for multiple rows or columns, but you're only using/defining a single row and column inside each of the two frames.

Comment: ... You might want to use it if, for example, you add things to `frame_2` besides the single label you have now.

Answer (score 0):

Since the grid manager doesn't know how many rows and columns there are to be on the main window, it doesn't allot the frames with the defined height and width.

If you add **padding** to each frame, you will see that the Text widget in not the upper left corner. But the Text widget will always be in the upper left corner as it has been placed on the 0th row and column.

Also, use rowconfigure and columnconfigure to ensure that the frames take the space specified by you on the main window.